# Can't access world wide web from PC on VLANs

Tags: vlan, internet

I do a static route on my local router

```
router
default-gateway 192.168.3.254

static route on router
192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.95
192.168.80.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.95
192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.3.95

3560-switch

gig0/1 no switchport
ip address 192.168.3.95 255.255.255.0

vlan 10
ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0
vlan 80
ip address 192.168.80.254 255.255.255.0
vlan 100
ip address 192.168.100.254 255.255.255.0

gig0/12
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 100

pc1 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.254
```

The above configuration is good, I can now access my router from pc1 on vlan 100, internet access display on my LAN but unfortunately I cannot access any WWW site. 
Please guide me, I'm still a newbie on this matter.

Comment: How do you know Internet access works on the LAN if WWW isn't working? How are you testing? Can you:

    "ping 8.8.8.8"

...from your LAN? If so, can you:

    "nslookup google.ca"

Comment: Your L3 switch is also acting as a router. If not already there, create a new static route on the switch that looks like "ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.3.x" where "x" is the ip address of router interface connected to the switch. You could also post the configs for review.

Comment: i figure it out  sir stevieb and user4565, i configure ip dhcp pool but i did not configure dns-server. now after i configure dns-server walla it works :)

Comment: In fact, you could access the World Wide Web from the PCs on the VLANs; you just couldn't access the web sites by DNS name, but you could access them by IP address. There is a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configure Static Routing and you want to access the internet from your VLANs, on the above configuration PC1 is connected to VLAN100 and give a static ip with a default-gateway VLAN IP.

Configure DNS-server to that VLAN with your router default-gateway will solve the problem and now access the internet.